# Spring-Cloud Zuul Ignore/Include Services

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Is it possible to have a negative pattern in zuul.ignoredServices ?
I want to load-balance the services that only has the name/virtualHostName as "hrerp*".

I can explicitly define these in zuul.routes. Any other possibilities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, negative patterns are not supported yet. Pull requests welcome.

Comment: A new property "zuul.includedServices" can take precedence over "zuul.ignoredServices". `ProxyRouteLocator` shall do a simple match for included services and update routes map.  Does this sound OK ?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate :

- Extended `ProxyRouteLocator` (`CustomProxyRouteLocator`) with
  overridden `locateRoutes()`

  - `locateRoutes` will consider`ZuulProperties.ignoredServices` as the ones
    to be included.
- Declared `CustomProxyRouteLocator` bean with `@Primary`
- Initiated `PreDecorationFilter` bean with `CustomProxyRouteLocator`, 
  and as `@Primary`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this which gives you full control over blocking and logging of those blocked requests:

Set this in your properties:

```
zuul:
   blockedServices: 'admin, forbidden'
```

Then create a filter class like this:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class BlockingFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Value("#{'${zuul.blockedServices}'.replace(' ', '').split(',')}")
    private List<String> blockedServices;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return FilterConstants.PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        if (isBlockedLocation()) {
            blockCurrentRequest();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isBlockedLocation() {
        String requestUrl = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURL().toString();

        Set<String> violations = blockedServices.stream()
            .filter(s-> requestUrl.matches(".*" +s +".*"))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        if (violations.size() > 0) {
            log.warn("Blocked illegal request {} which violated rules {}",
                     requestUrl,
                     violations.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" : ")));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * If they attempt to get to an internal service report back not found
     */
    private void blockCurrentRequest() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        //Set your custom error code
        ctx.setResponseStatusCode(NOT_FOUND.value());

        //Spring tends to use json for not found.  This just sets a message.
        ctx.setResponseBody("Page not found");

        //Blocks this request from continued processing.
        ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
    }
}
```